# python - getting file path in executable version

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe, os.path

I'm using
     os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
to get localization of data file, which is in the same folder as .py file.
Everything works great until I'm trying to make exe version (with py2exe) and then something happens, exe version of the same program is returning empty string as the path to its localization. I'm using 32 bit pyhon 2.7 on Windows 7 (64 bit) (i have to...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Comment: os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(" ____file____ ")) - works great :) thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `pkgutil` module to load resources. 
The following should work:

```
pkgutil.get_data('<your_module_name>', file_path)
```